# Several virtual member functions with different signature

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python

I'm using Boost Python to provide a python interface to some classes in C++.
I have found this situation that I'm not sure how to solve:

I have a class that has this member functions:

```
virtual void visit(const ReportClass r) = 0;
virtual void visit(const unsigned int category) = 0;
virtual void visit(const char* type) = 0;
virtual void visit(const char* name, const unsigned int id, const char &value ) = 0;
virtual void visit(const char* name, const unsigned int id, const unsigned short &value ) = 0;
virtual void visit(const char* name, const unsigned int id, const unsigned int &value ) = 0;
virtual void visit(const char* name, const unsigned int id, const MaskedAddr &value ) = 0;
virtual void visit(const char* name, const unsigned int id, const unsigned long long &value ) = 0;
```

I'm a bit lost on how to implement the python-boost part, I have seen how to proceed with virtual functions and overloaded functions but I don't know how to combine both.

And by the way, I see in the example that a virtual function returning an int (for example) should be implemented this way:

```
int f()
{
    return this->get_override("f")();
}
```

In my case they do not return anything I guess I should implement them this way:

```
void f()
{
     this->get_override("f")();
}
```

Is this correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: **overcharged** functions? What is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to bind **pure virtual (overloaded)** methods to Python, so they can *be overloaded from python*. The tutorial you have [already found](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/exposing.html#python.class_virtual_functions), explains that in part. In your specific case, C++ and Python do not interplay well with the overloading. While C++ allows it, Python forbids. You cannot have two methods with the name `f` in Python. What we will have to do is to *diverge* the python calls, so the user can implement the overriding from Python.

I'll write a smaller example, but you can abstract from that.

Let's start with the C++ plumbing. Your C++ bindings should look like this:

```
struct BaseWrap : Base, boost::python::wrapper<Base> {
    int f() {
        return this->get_override("__f1__")();
    }

    int f(int i) {
        return this->get_override("__f2__")()
    }

    int f(const char* s) {
        return this->get_override("__f3__")()
    }

    int f(const char* s, double d) {
        return this->get_override("__f4__")()
    }
};

//your module code will look like this
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example) {
  using namespace boost::python;
  class_<BaseWrap, boost::noncopyable>("Base")
    .def("f", pure_virtual(((int)(Base::*)())&Base::f))
    .def("f", pure_virtual(((int)(Base::*)(int))&Base::f))
    .def("f", pure_virtual(((int)(Base::*)(const char*))&Base::f))
    .def("f", pure_virtual(((int)(Base::*)(const char*, double))&Base::f))
  ;
}
```

What did we do? When the Python side of the code calls `f(<parameters>)`, we will resolve to the right overloaded method. This method will then call Python's `__f1__`, `__f2__`, etc, in which the meat of the method was really coded in, from Python.

To finalise the binding, in Python, you must inherit from `example.Base` and implement `__f1__`, `__f2__`, `__f3__` and `__f4__`:

```
class Base(example.Base):
  """Throw here the documentation of Base - don't bother about the C++ stuff"""

  def __init__(self,...):
    pass

  def __f1__(self):
    """Implementation of Base::f()"""
    pass

  def __f2__(self):
    """Implementation of Base::f(int)"""
    pass

  def __f3__(self):
    """Implementation of Base::f(const char*)"""
    pass

  def __f4__(self):
    """Implementation of Base::f(const char*, double)"""
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the easy question first: You can always "return this->get_override("f")();", even if the return type is void. Actually, in such wrapper code, I find that even the better choice, because if suddenly the wrapped function returns something, you will get a compile error!

Now the difficult question: How to mix virtual and overloaded functions here. I would circumvent this problem using the template method pattern. The idea is to simply provide a public, nonvirtual function that calls a private virtual function. Optionally, you can make the virtual one protected in order to allow extension instead of overriding. Further, in the nonvirtual one, you can verify pre/post conditions that the derived classes must fulfill or validate parameters (e.g. assert(name);).